# PHP division by zero error

Tags: php

I did some research about division by zero error in PHP. I found a couple of most of them said to do an if statement like I did with my code below, but I am still getting an error, can someone tell me what's wrong with my code?

```
<?php 

$result = array(
  'price' => 0,
  'special' => 80
 );

$product = array(
  'savings' => round((($result['price'] - $result['special'])/$result['price'])*100, 0)
 );

if ($result['price'] == 0) {
  echo $result['price'];
} else {
  echo "You will save " . $product['savings'] ."%"; 
}

?>
```

I tried both

```
If == 0 and if != 0
```

as I am fairly new to PHP, won't my if statement mean if the price of product = 0 than echo out the price and if it's not than echo out the special price?

I'm not allowed to move the `$product` array.

Comment: [Works for me](https://eval.in/389319)

Comment: @JohnConde hey i edited my code the price was set to 100 not to 0

Comment: the `if($result['price'] == 0)` check needs to be done _before_ this bit: `/$result['price']`. When assigning `$product`, you're dividing by 0, which is always wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to make more sense, money-wise: check first if the price is higher than the special, and if so, perform the calculation.

```
$product = array(
  'savings' => ($result['price'] > $result['special'] ? (round((($result['price'] - $result['special'])/$result['price'])*100, 0)) : 0)
 );
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to move the division inside your if/else statement.

```
$result = array(
  'price' => 100,
  'special' => 80
);

if ($result['price'] == 0) {
   echo $result['price'];
} else {
   $product = array('savings' => round((($result['price'] - result['special'])/$result['price'])*100, 0)
);
   echo "You will save " . $product['savings'] ."%"; 
}
```

Comment: That seems to work,but is it possible without moving the division?

Comment: No matter where you put the division, you MUST check to make sure the denominator is not equal to zero. Also - your code overwrites the product all together. It does not add an extra field.

Comment: Yes i know i was just trying to see how to avoid this error